# Pandas Dataframe Matrix Multiplication using @

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series, matrix-multiplication

I am attempting to perform matrix multiplication between a Pandas DataFrame and a Pandas Series. I've set them up like so:

```
c = pd.DataFrame({
    "s1":[.04, .018, .0064],
    "s2":[.018, .0225, .0084],
    "s3":[.0064, .0084, .0064],
    })
x = pd.Series([0,0,0], copy = False)
```

I want to perform `x @ c @ x`, but I keep getting a `ValueError: matrices are not aligned` error flag. Am I not setting up my matrices properly? I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: What is the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x @ c` returns a Series object which has different indices as `x`. You can use the underlying numpy array to do the calculation:

```
(x @ c).values @ x.values
# 0.39880000000000004
```